# Login failed when trying to perform git push to Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am on a Windows 10 machine, and this morning my git credentials were working as expected, and I was busy pushing and pulling code to our Azure Devops project. 
Now I cannot, from this specific VM anyways. When I do `git pull` I get the standard MS authentication prompt, and I can see my MS account (which is connected to windows via our federated AD)

[image]
I click on my account, and the prompt goes away, and I get an error in my prompt:

`Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Password for 'https://myOrg@dev.azure.com':`

If I enter my AD password (or anything else) I get a authentication failed message. I also tried to re-enter my credentials by selecting "Use another account" in the MS sign in window, and I get the same results.

I have seen issues that were solved by removing the cached credentials from the Credential Manager. So I go `Control Panel` -> `Credential Manager` and remove all of the credentials that are stored and try the git operation again.

I get the same MS login window, and oddly enough my account is still there, and Connected to windows (and fails the same way when I click on it)

So then I removed my accounts that were associated via `Settings` -> `Accounts` -> `Access work or school`. I could see my MS account there, so that looked promising, but same behaviour.
I tried to update git (it is v2.21.0.windows.1)
I also installed microsoft's [git credential manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) as per some answers that I found on SO and microsoft's forums. 
Still getting the same error.

I rebooted and removed all the credentials/accounts again, then tried from Visual Studio instead of calling git from the command line.

Same error!

My next steps are to rebuild my Windows profile which I am hoping will reset all this stuff. I am able to access the site from another VM, so it seems to be some sort of git configuration/cached credentials on this machine.

Any assistance/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: switch to ssh key?

Comment: you mentioned VM and federated AD, do you have any proxy / global proxy in your way?

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when moving my DevOps organisation to a different tenant. The only thing that resolved my issue was to remove the `tenant.cache` file from the GitCredManager, see:

> If you use Visual Studio or the Git command-line tool, you might need to clear the cache for the Git Credential Manager.
>   Deleting the %LocalAppData%\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache file on each client machine resolves the issue.

from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/connect-organization-to-azure-ad?view=azure-devops

Comment: This solved the problem for me - our Azure DevOps instance had moved between tenancies

Answer (score 1):

Try disconnecting from the team server.

[image]

Then try redoing your commit from the Team Explorer window, reconnecting if required.